# Java: Face Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: YES)) Exception

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to use Apache DBCP connection pooling technique with Spring and my DB is MySQL. My Apache DBCP configuration code is:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close") // destroyMethod attribute is used to close the bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));
    dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
    dataSource.setMaxTotal(5);
    return dataSource;
}
```

But When I try to run the program, it will throw an exception :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root    '@'localhost' (using password: YES))
```

For Resolving this exception, i already google it, and find out this answer :

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Login as root user. But unfortunately this will not work and an exception still occurs. So what should I do?

I was also trying to create new user and grant all privileges to new user, but still i face the same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice the extra spaces in the error message:

```
Access denied for user 'root    '@'localhost'
                            ^^^^
```

Remove the spaces and it will probably work.

Comment: how i remove this spaces ?

Comment: @HarmeetSingh Look at how your properties are defined in `environment`. If all else fails you could `trim()` them.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Rotteveel, you really great.. my issue was resolved. Thanks a lot. It mean, after grant permission, this will work?

Comment: @HarmeetSingh The grant permission was probably unnecessary

Comment: Thanks @Mark Rotteveel if we need, then execute grant permission command, other wise no need for grant permissions.

Comment: @HarmeetSingh I meant that root usually already has those rights, so for root it is usually unnecessary to use grant.